# CASCADE for dropIndex in CockroachDB

Tags: liquibase, cockroachdb

**Liquibase:**  Following liquibase wrote for removing `unq_customer_id` constraint.

```
 <dropIndex indexName="unq_customer_id"
            schemaName="public"
            tableName="CUSTOMER_LOGIN_EVENT"/>
```

I have used dropIndex, Since `CockroachDB` implements unique constraints by creating an index. `CASCADE` is required to deleted this index.

But, I am not sure how to use cascade in above liquibase script, since `dropIndex` XSD don't have option for `CASCADE`.

```
<xsd:element name="dropIndex">
    <xsd:complexType>
       <xsd:attributeGroup ref="tableNameAttribute"/>
       <xsd:attributeGroup ref="indexName"/>
       <xsd:attribute name="associatedWith" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

**Error:**

> ERROR: index "unq_customer_id" is in use as unique constraint (use
>   CASCADE if you really want to drop it) [Failed SQL: DROP INDEX
>   public.unq_customer_id]

Comment: Why do you want to use liquibase since CockroachDB isn't offically supported (https://www.liquibase.org/databases.html)? Have you considered flyway instead?

Comment: Liquibase falls back to standard SQL for operations, so even for non-officially supported datababases it will usually work just fine. For databases we've not tested against significantly, there may be some database-specific functionality we miss and/or some secondary functionality that doesn't work quite right. But nothing that should stop you from being able to use it in general.

Comment: I agree but the issue with CREATE and DROP INDEX is that there is no ANSI standard and every DB is a bit differently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct answer is that when the logic in any of the Liquibase functions do not meet your needs, your options are:

1. Specify the exact sql you want with the `<sql>` tag. This gives you control over exactly what will run, and allows you to anything with Liquibase that your database exposes over SQL

Example:

```
<changeSet id="1" author="xyz">
   <sql>DROP INDEX customer_login_event@unq_customer_id cascade</sql>
<changeSet>
```

2. Add a `<modifySql>` block to your changeSet. This allows you to still use the dropIndex tag, but tweak the SQL.

Example:

```
<changeSet id="1" author="xyz">
    <dropIndex indexName="unq_customer_id"
               schemaName="public"
               tableName="CUSTOMER_LOGIN_EVENT"/>
    <modifySql>
        <replace replace="unq_customer_id" with="customer_login_event@unq_customer_id"/>
        <append value=" CASCADE"/>
    </modifySql>
</changeSet>
```

But, I'd also ask if the better answer in your case is to script the dropping of the constraint rather than the index? DROP...CASCADE can be a scary call to make since you aren't seeing/controlling what is actually being dropped.

They do implement the constraint by making an index, but from your standpoint that should be just an implementation detail. If you had originally created a constraint, the more readable/understandable/safer thing may be to drop the constraint which should cause CockroachDB to drop the corresponding index rather than dropping the index in a way to transparently drop the constraint.

Comment: On CockroachDB it is rather DROP INDEX customer_login_event@unq_customer_id cascade

Comment: OK, then in that case it is probably easiest to fall back to the <sql> approach. I'll update the answer with the valid SQL

Comment: But, I'd also ask if the better answer in your case is to script the dropping of the constraint rather than the index? I have created constraint only but after that came to know instead of constraint CockroachDB created it as Index.

Comment: It's failing while executing Tests since database is H2, any assistance.  org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "DROP INDEX PUBLIC.CUSTOMER_LOGIN_EVENT@[*]UNQ_CUSTOMER_ID CASCADE "; SQL statement:

Comment: Yes, the SQL above is CockroachDB specific. If you are using only H2, you'll have to replace it with the H2-specific SQL. With the modifySql route, you can use the dbms attribute to target the modifications to only cockroachdb with dbms="generic". The built-in dropIndex generated sql will be correct for h2.